# Why does v-show need a wrapper element around a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My project shows four alternative puzzle games. By adjusting the value of `puzzle` I can show each of them; only one is shown at a time.

```html
<script setup>
const puzzle = ref('puzzleIndex');
</script>

<template>
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <word-wheel   v-if="puzzle==='wordWheel'"  ></word-wheel>
    <train-tracks v-if="puzzle==='trainTracks'"></train-tracks>
    <combi-word   v-if="puzzle==='combiWord'"  ></combi-word>
    <square-away  v-if="puzzle==='squareAway'" ></square-away>
  </div> 
</template>
```

I wanted to use `v-show` instead of `v-if` (reason given at the end). If I just change the `v-if`'s into `v-show`'s, *all the puzzles are displayed at the same time*. So I have had to use extra `div`s for the `v-show` condition:

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
  <div v-show="puzzle==='wordWheel'" >
    <word-wheel ></word-wheel>
  </div>
  <div v-show="puzzle==='trainTracks'">
    <train-tracks ></train-tracks>
  </div>
  <div v-show="puzzle==='combiWord'" >
    <combi-word ></combi-word>
  </div>
  <div v-show="puzzle==='squareAway'">
    <square-away></square-away>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this the case?

I want to use `v-show` because it does not re-render the component. So the user can switch between puzzles which have been half-completed, and switch back again later to finish each one. With `v-if`, each puzzle attempt is destroyed when it is closed, and it's necessary to start again if you switch back to it.

Comment: please share one of that components and its style

Comment: `v-show` applies CSS to the element it's on, hiding it, but it's still in the DOM. whereas `v-if` prevents the element or component from rendering to the DOM at all.  if it's a component element the CSS from `v-show` will be applied to the component's root element. This is the concept of [fallthrough attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#fallthrough-attributes). If you have multiple root elements, vue does not know which element to apply the attribute to so won't apply it to any. From the description of your problem, it sounds like you have multiple root elements.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim the components are fairly complex to show, and as yoduh suggests they have multiple root elements, so that is the reason.

Comment: @yoduh. thanks - multiple root elements. I'll add a simple playground demo as an answer (unless you'd like to!). I wasn't aware that multiple root elements were a problem - having now looked, docs suggests that warnings should be given, but I don't have any warnings.

Comment: Can you add the structure of one of the game?

Comment: The difference most definitely is well documented: there's a [whole page on conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html), which has a large [section on the difference between the two and their mechanisms](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show).

Comment: @DarrylNoakes, I meant that the docs don't explicity mention that you should use `v-show` if you want the state of the component to be preserved betweeen toggles - which is my only reason for using it.

Comment: I suppose. I understand the difference between "rendering" and "displaying", so I see that distinction in the docs; but to others it may not be so clear. I would add that the comparison section says that `v-if` "ensures that ... child components ... are properly destroyed and re-created during toggles."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yoduh mentioned in the comments, the issue is due to the use of a multi root component: a attribute or directive on a component with multiple root elements won't be applied, see the docs for [Attribute Inheritance on Multiple Root Nodes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes):

> Unlike components with a single root node, components with multiple root nodes do not have an automatic attribute fallthrough behavior.

[This](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) is a simple reproduction of the problem (notice the warning).

---

The simplest solution would likely be to just wrap the component in a single `div` element.
(Explicitly binding `$attrs` won't help in this case since `v-show` is not included in the `$attrs` object).

Comment: Strange that (unlike in your playground example) I did _not_ get any warnings from VS Code.

Comment: @quilkin, "from VS Code" - You mean in the browser?

Comment: No, the Visual Studio Code (Windows) that I'm using for development - no compile or lint issues; no errors or warnings in debug console.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken It's a runtime warning, not sure that the linter should be able to pick that up